# How to solve a NoSuchMethodError in a Spring Controller testcase?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.testAborted(Lorg/junit/ 
runner/Description;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)
        at  org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestM­ethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:
155)
```

And written testcase for controller like, newly writing testcases  for Spring Controller classes:

#### TestXController.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:D:/ABC/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/
xyz-servlet.xml", 
"file:D:/ABC/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/xyzrest-servlet.xml"}) 

    public class TestXController  { 

    @Inject 
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext; 

    private MockHttpServletRequest request; 
    private MockHttpServletResponse response; 
    private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter; 
    private XController controller; 

    @Test 
    public void setUp() { 
       request = new MockHttpServletRequest(); 
       response = new MockHttpServletResponse(); 
       handlerAdapter =  applicationContext.getBean(HandlerAdapter.class); 
       // I could get the controller from the context here 
       controller = new XController(); 
    } 

    @Test 
    public void testgoLoginPage() throws Exception { 

        request.setAttribute("login", "0"); 

        final org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView mav =  handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller); 
        assertViewName(mav, null); 
        assertAndReturnModelAttributeOfType(mav, "login", null); 
    } 

    @Test 
    public void testgoHomePage(){ 

        org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView mav =null; 

        request.setAttribute("success1", "1"); 
        request.setAttribute("success", "1"); 

                try { 
                        mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller); 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 

        assertViewName(mav, null); 
        assertAndReturnModelAttributeOfType(mav, "home",null); 
    }
```

Can any one Guide me on this to write test cases for Spring
Controller classes,Or any code samples links.

Thanks & Regards,  Venu Gopala Reddy.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, make sure you're using the right version of JUnit.  I think there's a mismatch with the Spring test JAR that forces you to use JUnit 4.4.

Comment: yes, as per spring test jar force,we are using the same JUnit 4.4 also getting same error msg on console.